# How do we create a widget in Vuejs using vue-custom-element and Vuejs3 in html?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, widget, vuejs3

I am trying to learn how to create a simple **VueJs Widget** using [vue-custom-element](https://github.com/karol-f/vue-custom-element) in a simple HTML page so I can use that page where ever it seems fit.

I am trying to add it by following

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue-custom-element@3.3.0/dist/vue-custom-element.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/document-register-element/1.4.1/document-register-element.js"></script>
<script>
  Vue.customElement('test-widget', {
    template: `<div>Hello World!</div>`
  });
</script>
```

Unfortunately, when I am trying to load the page I am seeing 2 **errors**

1. Uncaught TypeError: window.Vue.use is not a function
   at **vue-custom-element.min.js:6:9328**
2. Uncaught TypeError: **Vue.customElement is not a function**

I think it has something to do with the compatibility but not quite sure. So thanks in advance and remember I am trying to make it work on the HTML page, not on Vue CLI, and please suggest if there's any better way to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From `vue-custom-element`'s [Description](https://github.com/karol-f/vue-custom-element#description):

> Works with Vue 0.12.x, 1.x and 2.x

You're using `https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue`, which resolves to latest `3.x`.

Let's change Vue version to latest `2.x`:

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2/dist/vue.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue-custom-element@3.3.0/dist/vue-custom-element.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/document-register-element/1.4.1/document-register-element.js"></script>
<script>
  Vue.customElement('test-widget', {
    template: `<div>Hello World!</div>`
  });
</script>

<test-widget></test-widget>
```

Comment: Thanks! So if we want to create it in vue3 then how to do that?

Comment: @Hamza: two options: ***a)*** wait until `vue-custom-element` works with Vue3. ***b)*** write your own.